# php sort multinested array

Tags: php, sorting

im having troubles with sorting array with nested array etc. Array looks like this:

```
$array = array(
    "item" => array(
            "childs" => array(
                01 => array(
                    "name" => "Min",
                    "content" => "CC",
                    "number" => "111"
                ),
                02 => array(
                    "name" => "Min",
                    "content" => "BB",
                    "number" => "101"
                ),
                03 => array(
                    "name" => "Min",
                    "content" => "AA",
                    "number" => "115"
                ),
                04 => array(
                    "name" => "Min",
                    "content" => "BB",
                    "number" => "100"
                ),
            )
        ),
    );
```

I want to sort that array (childs to be specific) by CONTENT and NUMBER. Here's my code:

```
foreach ($array as $item) {
    foreach($item as $childs) {
        $row = array();
        $number = array();
        foreach($childs as $child) {
            $row[] = $child["row"];
            $number[] = $child["number"];
        }
        array_multisort($number, SORT_ASC, SORT_NUMERIC, $row, SORT_ASC, $childs);
    };
};
```

But it does not seem to work. I got no error but the array is not sorted. Can somebody give me a hand?

Comment: Please show what you expect. How will the data look after it is sorted?

Comment: One problem with your current approach is that the `$item` and `$childs` variables from the foreach loops are copies of the array content, so sorting them will not affect the original array.

Comment: I want the elements in child array to be sorted by number ASC and row ASC. How can I work on the original one? Use reference?

Comment: Yes, if you use a reference for both `$Item` and `$childs` I think your sort will work as expected.

Comment: hmm, when im adding an & then im getting an error

Comment: Here's an example: https://3v4l.org/qajVo (I did also change `$child["row"];` to `$child["content"];` there. I assumed that was just a typo.)

Comment: EDIT: Actually it doesnt work properly. It is sorted by number but not by the row as well.

Comment: nvm it does. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I guess root cause is: "when you loop array. Item in array is not reference variable (you have sorted in another array)".

You can try by passing reference variable.

```
foreach ($array as &$item) {
    foreach($item as &$childs) {
        $row = array();
        $number = array();
        foreach($childs as $child) {
            $row[] = $child["row"];
            $number[] = $child["number"];
        }
        array_multisort($number, SORT_ASC, SORT_NUMERIC, $row, SORT_ASC, $childs);
    };
};
```